# magento show / render one (1) block in two (2) places at the same time

Tags: php, xml, magento, zend-framework

*Sorry for the weird title, but I just spent half a day trying to find this and I am sure the answer exists somewhere already, but I can't find it... so I'm asking again with a searchable title that others may find one day.*

In a responsive magento theme, I want the topLinks block to show up in both the responsive menu that is only visible in mobile view and the footer. As both of those places are controlled by css and page-width, I need them to render in the template at the same time. I have this in page.xml

```
<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
    <... lots of other stuff ...>
    <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
    <... lots of other stuff ...>
</block>
```

This works just fine when I call `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks'); ?>`, but when I put the following, also in page.xml only the footer renders and the header does not.

```
<block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
    <... lots of other stuff ...>
    <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
    <... lots of other stuff ...> -->
</block>
```

What am I doing wrong, or how do I clone the results of the one block in the second location?

Comment: I believe this is a conflict either with the name or the 'as' section. Try changing one or both for the bottom (as well as the name used in getChildHtml.

Comment: I tried that... I changed the footer block in page.xml to as="topLinksCopy" and changed the name in footer.phtml as well and it renders, but it also stops the header from rendering. If you change the name="top.links" then you break the functionality as the actual links are added by other modules using the addLink action to top.links.

Comment: Hi Jon, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10664584/1512654

Answer (score 1):

khartnett, thanks for your answer. The solution is found here: [how to display toplinks at footer in magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664318/how-to-display-toplinks-at-footer-in-magento/10664584#10664584)

to be clear, this is what I did:

1) remove `<block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>` from the footer block in page.xml

2) keep the `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks'); ?>` as is in the footer.phtml

3) Create a new layout file in your custom theme called local.xml with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="footer">
            <action method="insert">
                <block_name_to_insert>top.links</block_name_to_insert>
                <sort_relative_to_other_childname/>
                <sort_before_or_after/>
                <alias>topLinks</alias>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```